# pdf.js start from the bottom of the document

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, pdf.js

We are making an implementation that will change to the previous document when roll up to the start of current document.

I would like, in that case, to start from the bottom of the document. Its not hard to accomplish from inside the code (viewer.js), but I wouldn’t  like  to change the original code from pdf.js so would make easier to update when needed.

Is there anyway to accomplish that, without changing the code from viewer.js?

Answer (score 0):

In function `scrollIntoView(element, spot)` of viewer.js, we did for now this:

```
if(window.parent.PDFStartBottom){
      parent.scrollTop = parent.scrollHeight - element.offsetTop - parent.clientHeight;
      return;
  }
```